# Filtering by nested object fields when lazy='joined' is set in relationship SQLAlchemy 1.4

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
class ContactType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'contact_type'
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)


class Contact(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'contact'

    first_name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)   
    contact_type_id = Column(ForeignKey('contact_type.id'), nullable=False)
    contact_type = relationship('ContactType', lazy='joined', innerjoin=True)
```

*ideally, I would filter by Contact.contact_type.name , but it doesn't work that way*

`query = select(Contact).where(ContactType.name == 'some_type')` - doesn't work

`query = select(Contact).join(ContactType).where(ContactType.name == 'some_type')` - works,
but since *contact_type = relationship('ContractorType', lazy='joined', innerjoin=True)*, it already makes a join (in other cases this feature is used)
an additional join of the ContactType table is dubbed JOIN (visible when echo= True)

if I use `contains_eager`

`query = select(Contact).options(contains_eager(Contact.contact_type)).where(ContactType.name == 'some_type')` - works, but
(*SAWarning: SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s) 'contact_type.  Apply join condition(s) between each element to resolve.*)

Please tell me how I can do this

Comment: You can use [has()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html#exists-forms-has-any), e.g., `query = select(Contact).where(Contact.contact_type.has(ContactType.name == "some_type"))`

Comment: Gord Thompson, thank you, working version :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same question in a SQLAlchemy GitHub discussion and they suggested this:

```py
query = (
    select(Contact)
    .join(Contact.contact_type)
    .options(contains_eager(Contact.contact_type))
    .where(ContactType.name == "some_type")
)
```

I checked it, and it works fine.